# How to re-format cURL command to AWS CLI s3 sync call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a curl command:

```
curl -C - "https://fastmri-dataset.s3.amazonaws.com/knee_singlecoil_train.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=<my-key>&Signature=<my-signature>&Expires=1634085391
```

I'm having trouble using AWS CLI sync, I'm doing this:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://fastmri-dataset/knee_singlecoil_train.tar.gz
```

I have the aws configure file setup with the access key, I set the secret up with the signature. I didn't otherwise get a secret.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The command to mimic that behavior is `aws s3 cp s3://.../ .`, that said, a signature is not a secret key.  To use the AWS cli, you will need the secret key.

Comment: Well, you can actually specify `--no-sign-request` to avoid giving a secret key, but that only works for Public objects. The object here is presumably a private object (since it has a presigned URL), so that would not work.

Comment: Well so it's slightly confusing actually. Its listed on aws's open data registry. But it does seem to be restricted. If you would be willing, please have a look here: https://registry.opendata.aws/nyu-fastmri/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first link is an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. It can be accessed via an HTTP/S call.

The AWS CLI command you have shown instructs the AWS CLI to synchronize the local directory with a file on S3. (This is actually incorrect, since you cannot sync a directory to a file.)

These two commands are **incompatible**. The AWS CLI cannot use a pre-signed URL. It requires AWS credentials with an **Access Key and Secret Key** to make AWS API calls.

So, you **cannot** reformat the curl command to an AWS CLI command.